# Drag and Drop div into table and get the data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I set the div data value in table cells, what I want is how to get the div data value, while drop.

In my code, I set the data in the table like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 function createDynamicTable(tbody, rows, cols) {

      if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) return;

    for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {

          var trow = $("<tr>");

         for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {

              var cellText = "Cell " + r + "." + c

            $("<td>")

                     .addClass("tableCell")

                      .text(cellText)

                     .data("col", c)

                     .appendTo(trow);

        }

         trow.appendTo(tbody);

     }

  }
```

In my code, on clicking the cell of table, I get the row and column data div values

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    createDynamicTable($("#tbl"), 10, 5);

     $("#tbl td.tableCell")

             .click(function() {

                 alert("Clicked Col=" + $(this).data("col"));

             });

 });
```

it is working perfectly

for full code view the site:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/linqed/archive/2009/03/04/generating-html-tables-with-jquery.aspx

I try like this but I cann't getting the table cell data value on stop event. How to get the setted data value in drag and drop.

```
$(".drag").draggable({

                    stop: function (ev, ui) {

                        var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
                        var oldData = $("#tbl td.tableCell").data('col');
                        alert(oldData);
                        }
});
```

Help me to get the data value in drag and drop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try $(ev.target).data('col');

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop could be restructuring the DOM. Try Using jQuery.live instead of jQuery.click (if supported by your [jQuery version](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) to bind the click event:

```
$("#tbl td.tableCell")
         .live('click', function() {
             alert("Clicked Col=" + $(this).data("col"));
          });
```

Since .live() is deprecated you may also want to try the .on() method (if using jQuery 1.7.x).

Comment: No html is not working, I drag the div element and drop over the table cell.